# MySQL Group By Sum by Day

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with

```
id int pk auto_inc | created int(11) | amount int | user_id int
```

I want to create a list of rows grouped by day totalling the amount field.

I have tried this:

```
SELECT created, sum(amount) as amount, id FROM total_log WHERE user_id = $this->user_id GROUP BY DAY(created)
```

This doesn't give the right results. They are getting grouped into one row.

The date is saved from dd/mm/yyyy format to unix time stamp like 1349046000

Comment: Should there be more than one row?  You have `where user_id = $this->user_id`.  This makes me think that there's only one row, even *before* the result set is grouped.

Comment: woops forgot to mention user_id. Nope there are multiple records for the same user_id

Comment: Hm..is it proper query? It would not event compile in sql server. Select clause has reference to "created" and "id" columns, which are used in the group by clause (day(created) is something different than created in those terms).

Comment: @Dooh -- mysql allows it, unfortunately.

Comment: are you trying **DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(created))** ?

Comment: What if you change your current `SELECT` with `SELECT DAY(created), SUM(amount)`?

Comment: @Matt Fenwick Huh.. So that's the dark part of the universe I'd rather avoid :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(created)) as d, 
    sum(amount) as amount
FROM total_log 
WHERE user_id = $this->user_id 
GROUP BY d
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't like mixing `day` and `int` columns:

```
mysql> select day(1349046000);
+-----------------+
| day(1349046000) |
+-----------------+
|            NULL |
+-----------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Incorrect datetime value: '1349046000' |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So all of your rows will have `NULL` for `day(some_int_value)`, and they'll all be in the same group.

I would suggest using a `date` or `datetime` type for that column instead.

Also, columns not in the `group by` clause should not be referenced in the `select` statement, unless an aggregating function is used on them.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
SELECT 
DAY(DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(created))), 
sum(amount) as amount 
FROM total_log 
WHERE user_id = $this->user_id 
GROUP BY DAY(DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(created)))
```